# How to tell generation of Intel processor of Macs on Apple's website?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, hardware, upgrade, processor

I'm trying to understand if both the non-touch bar and touch bar versions of Apple's new MacBook Pros have the same generation of processor inside, but Apple does not seem to list generation of processor on it's website under tech specs (which is very misleading because based on the clock speed and i5/i7 listing, it makes it look as if it's [last generation MacBook Pros](http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs-2015/) have better processors than its [newest machines](http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/)).

I notice that the non-touch bar MacBook Pro has slower RAM, but I'm not sure if this is because it's using an older processor or not.

**How can I get better technical details on the MacBook Pro processors (such as the generation) without having the MacBook in hand?**

Answer (score 2):

I'd check out other resources, such as EveryMac: http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/index-macbookpro.html

Although the details aren't there yet, they will be shortly, and they include the full CPU specs you're looking for.

Wikipedia also has details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Technical_specifications_4

Unclear what their source is though.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the wikipedia article but didn't know if I could trust it because I couldn't figure out their source either.

Answer (score 1):

They are using Skylake Processors according to [C|Net](https://www.cnet.com/news/lets-compare-the-old-macbook-pros-with-the-new-ones/).

> One of the biggest updates are the processors. Apple jumped from using
>   Intel Haswell processors to Skylake.

In another post, [C|Net explains why the 2016 MBP and the Surface aren't getting the latest and greatest Kaby Lake](https://www.cnet.com/news/intel-kaby-lake-7th-gen-core-processors-faq-update/) but rather sticking with Skylake

This is also confirmed by [Macworld.com](http://www.macworld.com/article/3060249/macs/macbook-2016-review-ultraportable-laptop-satisfies-with-speed-gains.html):

> The major changes are internal, so let’s focus on those. The MacBook
>   now has Intel Skylake processors, an upgrade over the Broadwell
>   processors used when the MacBook was introduced last year.

Comment: Can you confirm they're not just talking about the touch bar models though? Most sites seem to be reporting on just the touch bar models.

Comment: Found this "The starting model which we're using features a 2.0GHz dual-core Intel Core i5 processor with Turbo Boost speeds up to 3.1GHz"  That matches the 6th Gen Mobile (Skylake) specs on [Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/core/core-i5-processor.html) exactly.  There is no other processor with that spec

Comment: This helps too: [Apple Unveils Groundbreaking New MacBook Pro](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2016/10/27Apple-Unveils-Groundbreaking-New-MacBook-Pro.html)